# Add "silent" user to a group in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I have just installed a Ubuntu server that will hold a lot of different websites for which I want to add a CMS control panel.

For security reasons I will have all websites being owned by, for example, `site-x:site-x`.

The CMS site is owned by `www-data:www-data` and I need to add a silent permission to all sites so that `www-data:www-data` can read and write to their files... But they cannot read/write from each other or `www-data:www-data`.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add www-data into each of the other groups?  So that www-data is also a member of site-x group.  (and site-y, site-z, etc)

You can do this via usermod:  `usermod -a -G site-x www-data` will add the user www-data to the site-x group.  It can then write any files site-x owns, that has the group write bit on.

Answer (score 0):

However, adding www-data to sites groups isn't really secure. As I know www-data is user for apache webserver, and any malicious script from site-x can read/write site-y data when called from web.

I propose create special user for CMS, runs cms under suexec and add it to sites group.

Comment: How can it do that? If `www-data` belongs to group `site-x` it means that it can do everything the group `site-x` can. But user `site-x` cannot do everything that group `www-data` can and therefore it wouldn't be able to read/write `site-y`

Comment: I mean not site-x, but www-data user. For example, if you use mod_php on site-x, that all php scripts called through apache on site-x has beed executed under www-data user.